# How to correctly search an JavaScript object and push it from one js file into an array of another js file?

Tags: javascript, html, function, search

I am learning to implement JS dynamic pages.
 I have created 2 JavaScript files to display data dynamically in HTML. One JavaScript file data.js has two arrays of objects (catalogArray and myCartArry) and another JavaScript file (function.js) has a function`chargerArticles()` which loads those objects.  then creates HTML elements and display items (catalog) on HTML page.

The functionality I want to implement is:

1. When user will press 'Add to Cart' button, the `oneClick()`, it gets position of ith object (requested), this event should invoke `addToCart(pos)` function. (requesting to push certain object(item) into `myCartArry` from `catalogArray`)
2. `addToCart(pos)` will check (by obj name) if certain requested object is already exists in `myCartArry`or not, using `searchInCart(name)` function. `(searc/hInCart(catalogArray[pos].name))`
3. and on this basis if `searchInCart()` returns `false`(the object's name is not found into myCartArray[]), then object will be pushed into `myCartArry[]`of data.js.

I have written below code to do this but its not functioning, `onclick` event is not doing anything. Also`other function`is not working.  Please help me resolving this as data(object) is not being searched and inserted correctly. Where am I doing mistakes? Thank you.

```js
// data.js
var catalogArray = [
    {
      code: 100,
      name: "T Shirt c100",
      desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known as",
      price: 150,
      image: "./images/img100.jpg"
    },
    {
      code:101 ,
      name: "T Shirt c101",
       desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known as",
      price: 250,
      image: "./images/img101.jpg"
    },
  
    
  ];


  var myCartArray = [
    {
      name: "T Shirt c100",
      price: 150,
      qte:2,
      TotalPrice:150,
    }

    ];
    
    
    //function.js
    // var catalog=catalogArray;
function chargerArticles() { 

 var myShoppingCart = [];

 // var articleCmd = {}; //array of  objects
 //   articleCmd.name="aaaa";
 //   articleCmd.price="aaaa";
 //   articleCmd.qte="5";
 //   // articleCmd.priceTotal="567";
 //   myCartArray.push(articleCmd);


 var articles = document.getElementById("content");
 for (var i =0; i < catalogArray.length; i++) {


  //Product div
  var article = document.createElement("div"); 
  article.setAttribute("class", "as");
  //Unique id
  article.id=i+"-article";



  //Command Input Area
  var zoneCmd=document.createElement("div");
  zoneCmd.setAttribute("class", "border");
  
 
  var inputCmd=document.createElement("input");
  inputCmd.setAttribute("class", "qty");

  //inputcmd unique id
  inputCmd.id=i+"-qte";

  //inputcmd all properties
  inputCmd.type="number";
  inputCmd.value=0;
  inputCmd.min=0;
  inputCmd.max=5;

  inputCmd.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    console.log('blocked keydown e.key:', e.key);
  
    // prevent default input response
    e.preventDefault();
  });


  zoneCmd.appendChild(inputCmd); //child 1

  //Button of add to cart
  var button=document.createElement("BUTTON");
  button.setAttribute("class", "cartBtn hvr-underline-btn");
  // button.innerHtml = '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:36px"></i> Lägg till i kundkorgen';
  // button.setAttribute("class","sourceText fa fa-trash-o");
  //  $(button.sourceText).append('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'); 
  button.innerHTML = " ADD TO CART";

  //Button unique id
  button.id=i+"-cmd";

  button.onclick=function()
  {
   var item=this.getAttribute("id");
   var pos=item.substring(0,1);
   // document.getElementById("1234").innerHTML = "Hello World";
   addToCart(pos);
  }

  zoneCmd.appendChild(button); //child 2
  //zoneCmd child of article element
  article.appendChild(zoneCmd);
  //finally article as a child of articles 
  articles.appendChild(article);
 }
}

function searchInCart(name) //T-Shirt
{
 myShoppingCart=myCartArray;
 var name1=name;
 var stop=0;
 for (var i =0; i < myShoppingCart.length && stop==0; i++) {
  if(myShoppingCart[i].name==name1)
   {
    stop=1;
    console.log("Hello wooooorld!");
    return true;
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
  }

}
function addToCart(pos)
{

if(searchInCart(catalogArray[pos].name))
{
 alert("Already Exists!");  // display string message

}
else
{
 var ident=pos+"-qte";
 var quatity= document.getElementById("ident").value;
  if(quatity>0)
  {
   var articleCmd = {}; //array of  objects
   articleCmd.name=catalogArray[pos].name;
   articleCmd.price=catalogArray[pos].price;
   articleCmd.qte=quatity;
   articleCmd.priceTotal=articleCmd.price*articleCmd.qte;
   myCartArray.push(articleCmd);

  }
  else
  {
  // alert
  }
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <title>Daily Shop | Product</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick.css">
    <link id="switcher" href="css/color/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/sequence-theme.modern-slide-in.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
  </head>
  <!-- !Important notice -->
  <!-- Only for product page body tag have to added .productPage class -->
  <body class="productPage" onload="chargerArticles()">  
    
 <!-- SCROLL TOP BUTTON -->
    <a class="scrollToTop" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
  <!-- END SCROLL TOP BUTTON -->

  <p id="1234">aaaa</p>
  

<div class="mainDivClass">
  <section id="aa-product-category">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">
          <div class="aa-product-catg-content">
            <div class="aa-product-catg-head">
              <div class="aa-product-catg-head-left">
                <form action="" class="aa-sort-form">
                  <label for="">Sort by</label>
                  <select name="">
                    <option value="1" selected="Default">Default</option>
                    <option value="2">Name</option>
                    <option value="3">Price</option>
                    <option value="4">Date</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
                <form action="" class="aa-show-form">
                  <label for="">Show</label>
                  <select name="">
                    <option value="1" selected="12">12</option>
                    <option value="2">24</option>
                    <option value="3">36</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="aa-product-catg-head-right">
                <a id="grid-catg" href="#"><span class="fa fa-th"></span></a>
                <a id="list-catg" href="#"><span class="fa fa-list"></span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
            


           <section id="content">
    </section>
</div>

    
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  
    <script src="js/function.js"></script>
    <script src="js/data.js"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To see the error you can check the console. Sadly your logic of how to retrieve the position `pos` in the click event will not work due to scope issues. Using `var pos = ~~this.id[0]` inside the click event should work tho. Alternatively you can just assign it differently, like `button.onclick = addToCart.bind(null, i)`.